# PostgreSQL SELECT date between date1 and date2

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have some problems with DATE

```
select name, extract (month from "date") between extract (month from "date")= 9 
and extract (month from "date") = 2 as "O-W"  from table1
```

I have a query in which I want to select a date (month) between month nine and twelve, but I can't.

Comment: It is unusual to want to select months without regard to the year.  But if you want to filter data, you should have a `where` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want:

```
select name
from table1
where extract (month from "date") between 9 and 12
```

Comment: If I want select to have: name,"O-W" (month) and after `where extract (month from "date") between 9 and 12`

Comment: something like: 
`select name,extract (month from "date") 
from table1
where extract (month from "date") between 9 and 12`  ?